# How to made local network in VMWare ESXi 5.5?

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, ip, local-area-network

I want to make alternative for mikrotik or cerio routers for ESXi. I need to setup virtual machine with debian and configure iptables. It will work like router. And i need to made local network in ESXi. How to made local network with its own ip pool in VMWare ESXi 5.5?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply create a new vSwitch1 e.g. which is not connected to any physical network card. Connect all local VMs to only this vSwitch. Then, connect your router VM to both vSwitch0 and vSwitch1, thereby making it possible to inspect the traffic for the interal VMs. It´s also a decent solution for virtual environments on a root server.